# Views block: select one item from each content type

Tags: 7, views

I am using a flexslider views block for the homepage of a site. There are content types such as news, articles, announcements... In that views block I would like to display the latest item of each content type.

I played around with the filter and sorting settings in the views admin panel but could not manage to list the items that way. I can either list the latest item -no matter what content type, or list the latest items of a certain content type -only one type. I tried to group the results in someway and that also was not what I need.

I found a [related question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33683/views-show-table-of-titles-of-last-nodes-for-each-content-type) but there seems to be no useful solution on that page.

Any ideas how I can manage this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is easy. Simply create the most recent item for each content type on a different attachment display, and combine them all into the views block display. That is only way you will be able to achieve that

Comment: Thank you @4life. This is almost working but there is one problem. When I add attachments to the main view, I get two sliders instead of one. So my slider consists of "li" items in a "ul" and what I need is to add "li" items to this. Yet, this method creates new "ul" items. Is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: Similarly I've managed to get the attachments working but is rendering as a list and not a slider. Did you end up finding a solution for this?